# ionic 2 : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I was working for a while on ionic 2 and I just updated my cordova and ionic and also android sdk build tools. I created a new project and then I tried to run the app on android application.

I did: `ionic cordova platform add android`. It worked.

Then I am doing: `ionic cordova run android` but I am getting this error.

Although I have set the icons in the resources and ionic resources command is running successfully. How can I solve this issue.

> :processDebugResources ..\platforms\android\res\xml\authenticator.xml:5:19-31
>   : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with
>   value '@mipmap/icon').
>
> FAILED
>   ..\platforms\android\res\xml\authenticator.xml:6:24-36
>   : AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'smallIcon'
>   with value '@mipmap/icon').

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Can you make sure, that within `authenticator.xml` you are referencing to a valid `icon` drawable?

Comment: android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:smallIcon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>

Comment: This is what I have, I don't think it is referencing. I don't know why. Should I replace it every time I do an 'ionic cordova platform add android'?